# select all the rows until date diff is 4 from bottom

Tags: mysql

I want to select all the rows from table where date different between two row is 4 or less and stop as soon as condition don't match ie diff > 4 in descending order i.e.(from bottom)

> caution: once condition is > 4 it will not match further it simply
>   stops

i.e it will have to select 5,6,7,8,9

[image: table]

I tried using "**HAVING**", but its slow on big data

Thank you all in advance to helping figure it out.

Comment: I'm thinking that the easiest solution is to use procedural logic, iterating through each row until your conditions are met. Are you looking for a SQL query to do the work for you ? what have you tried ?

Comment: can you post your table and data structure on http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: @raheelshan http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/157de/1

Comment: @Kickaha here is query http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/157de/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [user-defined variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/user-variables.html) to track the previous `updated_at` value (in my example below, in `@t`) then calculate from that whether the record is desired based on whether the previous record was desired (`@b`) and, if so, the difference between that last date and the current one:

```
SELECT   id, amount, updated_at
FROM (
  SELECT   my_table.*,
           @b:=IF(@b, DATEDIFF(@t,updated_at)<=4, FALSE) okay,
           @t:=updated_at
  FROM     my_table, (SELECT @b:=TRUE, @t:=MAX(updated_at) FROM my_table) init
  ORDER BY updated_at DESC
) t
WHERE    okay
ORDER BY updated_at, id
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1430b/1/0).

Comment: thanks it work like charm and fast too, how ever i still need a bit more there, would appreciate if you can have a look http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93d75/3

Comment: @JapanPro: That's a different question. Please post as a new question on here.

Comment: here is new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12171451/select-all-the-rows-until-date-difference-condition-match-with-grouping