# select all the rows until date difference condition match with grouping

Tags: mysql

with reference to this question

[select all the rows until date diff is 4 from bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170706/select-all-the-rows-until-date-diff-is-4-from-bottom)

Solution works great but how to group by customer_id and for each customer_id group by 4 day diff, 8 day diff

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93d75/3

Comment: With some example data, could you show the expected resultset?

Comment: here is expected chart http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f207/2

Comment: It's a lot better if you just paste in the SQL right here using proper code formatting as having to visit external links tends to be discouraging, especially for just a handful of lines of actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to keep track of the latest `customer_id` and perform the 'okay' logic on that too:

```
SELECT   amount, customer_id, updated_at, date_diff
FROM (
  SELECT   *,
           @b:=NOT @c<=>customer_id
               OR (@b AND DATEDIFF(@t,updated_at)<=date_diff) AS okay,
           @c:=customer_id,
           @t:=updated_at
  FROM     my_table, (SELECT 4 AS date_diff) init
  ORDER BY customer_id, updated_at DESC
) t
WHERE    okay
ORDER BY customer_id, updated_at, id
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36b22/1/0).